# Understanding of callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, callback

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) explanation here, but am still unsure how callbacks work.

I do my call here:

`scene.foo(scene.myCallBack("mymap"));`

And my callback stuff here:

1) scene.foo calls foo and passes in CallBack function with "mymap" JSON data

2) foo's $.ajax defines its success as the passed in CallBack. Once the data is processed, `success` calls the callback, `myCallBack()`

3) `myCallBack` attempts to `getJSON` from the file name and console.log it as a string with JSON.stringfy

Am I not understanding this correctly?

```
foo : function (callback) {
    $.ajax({
        success: callback //once AJAX request is successfull, $.ajax will call callback (myCallBack) and pass response back to callback
    });
},
myCallBack : function (name) {
    $.getJSON("C:/Users/danniu/Desktop/JavaScript/tilemap/maps/" + name + ".json", function (data) {
        var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log("json: " + this.myJSONText);        
    });
},
```

Comment: 1. Nope. It passes its execution result

Answer (score 0):

You're close to the solution.

`scene.foo(scene.myCallBack("mymap"));` first exectue `scene.myCallBack("mymap")` and then the result is passed to `scene.foo(...)`

It's similar to write:

```
var result = scene.myCallBack("mymap");
secene.foo(result);
```

This is pretty weird in this case, because `scene.myCallBack("mymap");` doesn't return anything interesting to `scene.foo`

Note that `$.getJSON(...)` already does an Ajax request for you.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I know $.getJSON already does AJAX request. But when I asked it here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029658/json-stringify-returning-undefined?noredirect=1#comment33396886_22029658, I wasn't really sure why $.getJSON wasn't returning anything

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you stick parentheses on, it stops being a callback. `scene.myCallBack` can act as a callback; `scene.myCallBack("mymap")` is just `undefined` (the return value of your function, as it does not have an explicit `return` statement and thus implicitly returns `undefined`).

If you want to have he `$.ajax` do `myCallBack` on success AND have custom arguments with it, you need to wrap it:

```
scene.foo(function() { scene.myCallBack("mymap"); });
```

Or equivalently,

```
fooCallback = function() { scene.myCallBack("mymap"; };
scene.foo(fooCallback);
```

**EDIT** to clarify some concepts:

> And can you explain why putting parentheses on it makes it not a callback?

Putting parentheses on a function executes a function, giving a value back. A callback must be a function.

For example, let's say your Mum wants you to eat an apple when you get home. She could leave you a note, "Growler, when you get home, eat an apple!":

```
var eatApple = function() {
  growler.eat('apple');
}

growler.on('getHome', eatApple);
```

is one way to write such a thing. However, if you write

```
growler.on('getHome', eatApple());
```

it's like your Mum feeding you an apple, then writing a note "Growler, when you get home, *_*_" and placing the apple core on the blank. I don't know about you, but I'd be rather surprised by such a note; and I daresay your JavaScript interpreter is likewise surprised as well.

A callback is a function to be done at a later time. If you execute it (with parentheses), you are only left with the function's *results*; and thus the function is not a callback, since your event will try to call back the *result* (the apple core), and not the function (process of eating an apple).

(An advanced topic is a function that *returns* a function; in this case, the result can be the callback, such as, `growler.on('getHome', whatShouldIDoNow())`. `whatShouldIDoNow` is still not a callback; the *function that it would return* would be.)

> If $.getJSON is already an AJAX request, how can I get the callback from that?

I do not understand the question. You *provide* `$.getJSON` with callbacks at the time you invoke it; those functions will be called back at the appropriate time, if such happens.

Comment: Thanks for this. If $.getJSON is already an AJAX request, how can I get the callback from that? And can you explain why putting parentheses on it makes it not a callback?